# Accessing name-based virtual host from an Android device

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have several name-based virtual hosts running on my local Apache 2.2 server on my Windows PC. Now, I would also like to access these virtual hosts from a remote device connected to my PC by WiFi Hotspot but this doesn't seem to be working.

**Here's what I did:**

1. Connect my phone to my PC's hotspot
2. Try to access a virtual host by name
3. Try to access it by IPv4

**Here's what I observed:**

1. I cannot access virtual hosts by name
2. I can access IPv4 but only for the time when Windows is identifying the hotspot network just after when I turn it on. As soon as windows is done identifying, IPv4 becomes inaccessible.

Am I missing something? I would prefer to access these virtual hosts by name instead of IP address.

Comment: How did you set this WiFi network up? Basically, what you’ll need is a configurable DNS server.

Comment: @DanielB : I enabled the WiFi Hotspot from `cmd`. That's it. And I'm sorry but I don't know so much about DNS servers.